# Why the component cannot read the data returned by service in angular and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have spent hours but couldn't get it.

I have written a web api get method which returns a simple array.

```
 public Hero[] getHeroes() 
        {
            return new Hero[] { new Hero { Id = 1, Name = "Hunain Hafeez-1" }, 
                                new Hero {Id= 2,   Name = "Hunain Hafeez-2" } 
            };
        }
```

and

```
   [HttpGet]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public IEnumerable<Models.Hero> GetHeroes()
    {
        
        LocalHeroes= heroes.getHeroes();

        return LocalHeroes;
    }
```

now in angular

service.ts

```
 getHeroesFromWebAPI(): Observable<any>
  {    

      
        return of(this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44320/api/values").subscribe(res => JSON.stringify(res)));
     }
```

in component.ts

```
 getHeroes(): void
   {
      
      this.heroService.getHeroesFromWebAPI().subscribe( r => {this.HeroesWebAPI= r; 
        console.log("STRINGFIED:"+  this.HeroesWebAPI)});
      
      
   }
```

and whereas

```
HeroesWebAPI: any[]= [];
```

now in the component's `getHeroes` method, the  t`his.HeroesWebAPI` returns `Object Object` and when I try to `stringify` it, it throws `CANNOT CONVERT CIRCULAR STRUCTURE TO JSON` error.

How to solve this?

Comment: A few things. HttpClient already returns observable for methods like get, you do not need to wrap it in of() and also remove the subscribe because subscribe doesn’t return anything, hence the undefined. Also don’t stringify JSON, just use the JSON as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your service like below.

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

getHeroesFromWebAPI(): Observable<any>
{    
  return this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44320/api/values").pipe(
    map(res => JSON.stringify(res))
  );
}
```